# Wrong use statement for Stripe in a Symfony2 Controller

Tags: php, symfony, stripe-payments, libraries

I'm using [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs) to make Payments for my [Symfony2](https://symfony.com/) web application and get an error trying to use the Stripe methods.

```
Attempted to load class "Stripe_Charge" from namespace "UserBundle\Controller".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

I used [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to include the Stripe librarie like this :

Composer :

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    [...]
    "stripe/stripe-php": "dev-master"
}
```

In my controller, I have the executePaymentAction function but I have an error using Stripe in it.

Here is my Controller :

```
<?
namespace UserBundle\Controller;

use Stripe\Stripe;

class RegistrationSellerController extends Controller
{
    public function executePaymentAction(Request $request){

        $data = $request->request->all();

        Stripe::setApiKey('pk_test_***');
        try {
            Stripe_Charge::create([
                'amount' => 2000, // this is in cents: $20
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'card' => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                'description' => 'product description'
            ]);
        } catch (Stripe_CardError $e) {
            // Declined. Don't process their purchase.
            // Go back, and tell the user to try a new card
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty obvious: You forgot the use statement for class `Stripe_Charge`

Comment: Actualy, I didnt the corect use statement for this but it works fine using \Stripe\Charge::create (I found it 2 mins after posting the answer)... sorry

Comment: `use Stripe\Charge` and then in your code: `Charge::create`. Same with `Stripe\CardError`